# ASP.NET - Add/Remove button css dynamically using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

I have a jQuery popup in which I have a asp.net button and an asp.net option button. The popup is shown using a link button. When the user click on link button, the popup will be shown.

I have a css style property for the button. Below is the CSS code

```
.btninfo {
    background-color: #00C0EF;
    border-color: #269abc;
    color: #fff;
}

    .btninfo:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #00ACD6;
        border-color: #269abc;
    }
```

When the popup is loaded initially, I am disabling the button using the below code.

```
$("[id*=lnkBtn]").live("click", function () {
            $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDelete").show();
            $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDelete").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDelete").css("color", "#fff").css("background-color", "#C8CBCB").css("border-color", "#C8CBCB");
            a.parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
            return false
        });
```

Once the option button is selected, I am enabling the button using the following code

```
$("[id*=opnSelect]").live("click", function () {
            $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDelete").show();
            $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDelete").css("color", "#fff").css("background-color", "#00C0EF").css("border-color", "#269abc");
           $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDelete").addClass('.btninfo:hover');
            $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDelete").prop('disabled', false);
        });
```

Everything is working fine but i am not able to apply the hover css for the button. i tried the below function but its enabling the button hover css but when the mouse has been moved it not changing the background color to initial state.

```
$(function () { $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDelete").mouseover(function () { $(this).css("background-color", "#00ACD6") }); });
```

Can anyone please let me know where I am doing wrong?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? .live() has been deprecated for about 5 years. Use .on() instead. Also, why are your jQuery selectors like this: $("[id*=opnSelect]")?? I think this should simply be $('#opnSelect')

Answer (score 2):

use classes instead of css and then add and remove the class as needed

```
.btninfo {
background-color: #00C0EF;
border-color: #269abc;
color: #fff;
}

.btninfo:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #00ACD6;
    border-color: #269abc;
}

//new class with styles for disabled button
.btnDisabled{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #C8CBCB;
    border-color: #C8CBCB;
}
```

and then in your code

```
//when disable button add this class btnDisabled
   $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDelete").addClass('btnDisabled').removeClass('btninfo');

//when enable  button add back the original class which inlcudes the `hover` styles
    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDelete").addClass('btninfo').removeClass('btnDisabled');
```